# JS Regex convert zeroes into following range XX.xxxxxx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to see if it's possible to use JS Regex to convert user's data entry into zeroes if user enters one digit before the decimal or less than 6 digits after the decimal. For example:

- 2.45 converts into -> 02.450000
- Data entry of 0 (this includes 0.0 or 0.00 or 0.000 etc) is not a valid value

I tried the following regex expression, but it doesn't add the missing zeroes to the data:

`^[+-]?((([0-9][1-9]{1,2})|[1-9])|([1-9][0-9]{1,2})|([1-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]{1,6})|([1-9][0-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]{1,6})|(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.\\d{6})$`

Comment: I just updated my answer with the regex expression that I currently have in placed

Comment: Should a user always enter a number, and should there always be a dot entered by themselves? And what if a user enters 7 digits after the dot?

Comment: `conv = n => { const [base, dec] = n.split('.'); return (!+base ? base : base.padStart(2,'0'))+'.'+(dec||'').padEnd(6,'0') };  console.log(conv('2.45'))`

Comment: Do you need to use a regex? toFixed looks like a good candidate for the fractional part

Comment: `str < 1 || str >= 10 ? (+str).toFixed(6) : '0'+(+str).toFixed(6)`

Comment: @user120242 thank you so much! Both of your solutions worked really well. Really helpful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE TO use Regex?
if not:

```
data=2.45;
whole=Math.floor(data);
fraction=data-whole;
formatted=("0"+whole).slice(-2)+"."+(fraction+"00000").slice(2,8);
// "02.450000"
```

what if data>=100?!?

```
("2").padStart(9, '0')
// "000000002"
```

```
"0".repeat(10)
// "0000000000"
```

Comment: Did it work for you/my answer is good?
If so, please select and up-vote it.
Thanks!